# ESP32 can't connect to MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, iot, esp32

I'm trying to make a project with master/slave architecture. This is the code for my master node.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it can't connect to the broker. Last time I tried it with an ESP8266 it works. Because I need bluetooth connection that's why I'm switching board. I'm using HiveMQ broker.

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

#define DHTPIN 4
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

// WIFI
const char *ssid = "xxx";
const char *password = "xxx";

// MQTT
const char *MQTT_SERVER = "x.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud";
const int MQTT_PORT = 8883;  // Use an integer for MQTT port
const char *MQTT_USERNAME = "x";
const char *MQTT_PASSWORD = "x";
const char *MQTT_CLIENT_ID = "esp32_master";

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
char sensorData[50];

/****** root certificate *********/
static const char *root_ca PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32_Master");
  Serial.println(F("Master has started!"));
  dht.begin();

  if (!connectToWiFi()) {
    // If WiFi connection fails, you might want to handle it accordingly.
    // For simplicity, I'm setting up MQTT only when WiFi is successfully connected.
    espClient.setCACert(root_ca);
    client.setServer(MQTT_SERVER, MQTT_PORT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected() && WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) reconnect(); // check if client is connected
  handleData();

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (it's a very slow sensor)
  int h = dht.readHumidity();
  int t = dht.readTemperature();

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  String sensorData = "{\"id\":\"0\",\"temperature\":" + String(t) + ",\"humidity\":" + String(h) + "}\n";
  Serial.println(sensorData);

  // Send sensor data to MQTT
  if (client.connected()) {
    client.publish("suhu", sensorData.c_str());
    Serial.println("Data sent to MQTT broker");
  }

  // You can use the sensorData array for other purposes beyond printing
  // For example, you might want to store it in a database, etc.

  delay(10000);  // Adjust the delay according to your requirements
}

void handleData() {
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    // Read data from slave via Bluetooth
    String data = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');

    // Send data to MQTT
    if (client.connected()) {
      client.publish("suhu", data.c_str());
      Serial.println("Data sent to MQTT broker");
    }
  }
}

bool connectToWiFi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  int attempts = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && attempts < 10) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(F("Connecting to WiFi..."));
    attempts++;
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
    return true;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to WiFi");
    return false;
  }
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    String clientId = "ESP32_Master";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str(), MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_PASSWORD)) {
      Serial.println("connected");

      // client.subscribe("led_state");   // subscribe the topics here

    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");   // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone have the same issues.

```
Connecting to WiFi...
Connecting to WiFi...
Connecting to WiFi...
Connected to WiFi
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

Comment: What have you done to try and debug the problem before asking? Have you looked up what error code -2 means? What do the broker logs show?

Comment: You appear to be calling `client.setServer(MQTT_SERVER, MQTT_PORT);` if, and only if, `connectToWiFi()` returns `FALSE`?

Comment: @hardillb I tried to create another server and credentials to know if it's issue with the broker or not. Because -2 means error connecting to the broker if I'm not wrong, and broker doesn't has any logging so there's no possibility to do that. I'm trying to code it all over by finishing mqtt first, and it's working now. I will be adding more functions to achieve the feature that I want. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Brits Thank you for addressing that, I was confused with the condition too. It's my fault, and I tried the condition to be true. It's working as intended. Because I want the system to not use WiFi and not publishing to MQTT if WiFi is not available. Sorry it was totally my fault, I'm so exhausted and hopeless

Comment: Not at all, it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

It was totally my fault.

```
if (!connectToWiFi()) {
    // If WiFi connection fails, you might want to handle it accordingly.
    // For simplicity, I'm setting up MQTT only when WiFi is successfully connected.
    espClient.setCACert(root_ca);
    client.setServer(MQTT_SERVER, MQTT_PORT);
}
```

The if condition was actually set to false, and it should be true. So changing `if (!connectToWiFi())` to  `if (connectToWiFi())` solved the issue.

I tried to redo my code, add feature one by one to test if it works then continue. Now I'm adding Bluetooth to master, so it can receive data from a slave, I don't know if receiving data from 2 ESP32 is possible with Bluetooth.